# Make a list of file more user friendly

Tags: list

i'm a business user for sharepoint, i would like to know if is possible (writing code or installing tool) to make a list of documents more user friendly in order to allow user to be fast in the research process.
I'm just looking for some ideas since i haven't find anything so far.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some free list filter solutions out there that helps you to find listitems quickly. Here is one basic but good working example that I tried:

http://jasear.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/sharepoint-2010-basic-list-search-filter-webpart/